# How can I use variables set from a terminal shell script in a new terminal window or tab? (OSX)

Tags: linux, macos, bash, ssh, global-variables

Environmental Variables or exporting of variables doesn't seem to work for me... I see that many versions of this have been covered, but they seem very specific and i'm getting confused.

I'm creating a my first shell script on OSX 10.9. The script does the following so far:

1) Ask user a series of questions such as server ip address, server port, ssh login user name and other variables.

2) Using the variables the user set, it then connects to a linux box (ubuntu 14) via ssh.

3) Once the ssh connects, the terminal launches a program called `iperf3` to run on the server using the `ip` and `port` specified by the user from the script.

So far all of these steps work so far.

The problem is that once the iperf program begins listening on that port specified by the script, all terminal commands are halted. In order to run iperf3 on my client, at this point, I need to open a new tab or window, and run the commands manually.  I would rather have the new tab continue off of the script.

However, even if I run the commands manually, these new tabs or windows in terminal do not know the variables that the user had set before hand from the script.  I've been trying the export command and looking into setting environmental variables but i'm rather confused and lost.

The next steps would ideally run from the one script file I created and proceed to do as follows:

4) Create new tab and launch `iperf3` using the `ip` and `port` specified by the user.

5) Upload the `--json` file created to a MySQL database running on the linux box.

iperf, for those who do not know, tests the network bandwidth between a client and host with results posted to the terminal. I need to test bandwidth at many different places wirelessly and automating most of the "copy paste" commands will save a lot of time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two tricks about passing data between scripts:

a) using a little file containing the data and then get it using:
to write:

```
echo $ip >> tmpfile
echo $other_data >> tmpfile
```

to get it back:

```
var=$(cat tmpfile)
# You'll get one value per line and you can use it with something like
while read line
do
    ##do some job...
done < tmpfile
```

b) using '&' at the end of the line to call a script that you don't want to wait, so you don't need another tab or script...

for further reference:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

To get this straight, you are outputting the variables to a temporary file, then loading the temp file in a new window?

I can see my variables being added to the temp file (with dupes but not really a problem). But it still doesn't read the variable.

for instance:
'S_IP=192.168.1.12'
'echo "S_IP="$S_IP >> tmp1 #from script'
'#new window'
'var=$(cat tmpfile)'
'echo $S_IP'
'#comes back blank''

Do I have to use while read line?
Sorry, i'm trying to format the comment here, but it's proving to be a challenge. =[

Comment: For now, i'm i'm creating a temp file based on the info you gave me on the desktop which writes out new code to run iperf3.  I just need to have the script auto open a new tab and load the temp.sh file to execute the command.

Comment: yes: I'm putting the values in a temporary file. Maybe is easier to simply write the values in the order do you gonna read it:

Comment: yes: I'm putting the values in a temporary file. Maybe is easier to simply write the values in the order do you gonna read it:

`#this is important to clear the file... or just use '>' instead of '>>' the first time you write to the file...
    touch tmp1
    S_IP=192.168.1.12
    echo $S_IP >> tmp1
    S_Other=theuser
    echo $S_Other >> tmp1`

... and when you read, you know that the first line es S_IP, and the second is S_Other, and so on... to read line by line use:

`while read line   #remember that line is a variable...
     do
          some=$line
     done < tmp1`

Comment: I was able to get it to work based on your notes.  Thank you so much. 
`echo "#!/bin/bash" > /Users/$USER/Desktop/temp.sh`
`open -a Terminal.app /Users/$USER/Desktop/temp.sh`
`echo "iperf3 -c "$S_IP -p $S_PORT >> /Users/$USER/Desktop/temp.sh`
`chmod 700 /Users/$USER/Desktop/temp.sh`
`iperfServer #this runs the iperf3 server listening.`